# Classification ANN accuracy results interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, accuracy, learning

I am currently implementing a simple feed forward ANN to a classification problem with 3 possible outcomes/classes. The results don't look great, therefore, I am currently thinking about whether my ANN even learns anything. All accuracy numbers in the following are related to the cross validation accuracy.

From my point of view, if it would not learn anything, it would either assign classes randomly or it would assign each observation the same class. As I have a balanced dataset, this would mean that the accuracy should be at 33.3% if the ANN is not learning anything. Is this a correct analysis? Or would 50% imply not learning anything because it is a coin toss whether our prediction fits or not? I am really confused that this is not a binary class setting but that we have three classes.

Currently, my Network starts training at around 33.3% and learns until approximately 50%. Does this imply that is learns something?

It just feels weird to me that it kind of cannot exceed the 50% mark if not learning anything would be at 33.3%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a balanced 3 class dataset random chance gives you an accuracy of 33.3%, and a network with accuracy similar to random chance means it learns nothing.

An accuracy of 50% means it learns something in this scenario assuming a balanced dataset. If you can edit your question with the architecture of your NN I can perhaps give advice on how to make some architectural improvements.

Comment: You are right the network was able to learn. I included now PCA and some other features and the accuracy increased to 70%. However, now I have a different problem that I can't explain. While the accuracy increases the loss function of the validation data set increases as well. How is this possible?

Comment: With respect to the model architecture: Feed forward NN with 4 hidden layers (fully connected) tanh activation function and output layer with softmax classification. I am using L2 regularization and adam gradient descent

Comment: @J3lackkyy try using relu activation for the hidden layers. Tanh and Sigmoid for hidden layer activations is very oldschool, and can lead to dying gradients for deeper architectures, resulting in incredibly slow convergence. If you're using tensorflow or pytorch I recommend also adding BatchNorm layers after each hidden layer which will also improve convergence.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I am still confused how it even possible that the loss is increasing while the accuracy increases?

Comment: @J3lackkyy loss is a measure of how close the predictions are to the true values while accuracy measures if the largest prediction matches the true value. Loss increasing while accuracy is also increasing means that the **confidence in the output is getting worse** while the **highest confidence output is tending to be correct**. This is far from an ideal scenario: we want both high confidence (low loss) and for the highest confidence predictions to be correct (high accuracy). Metrics such as AUC-ROC or AUC-PR take into account confidence as well and give you more insight than accuracy alone.

Comment: what would you suggest how I should approach this problem then? More regularization?

Comment: couldn't it also be induced by the L2 regularization? That the penalty somehow increases the loss function?

Comment: @J3lackkyy without knowing all the details of your network, dataset, loss and optimizer it is difficult to point to a specific cause.

Comment: @J3lackkyy I have created a chat room for us to continue discussing this https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127141/classification-ann-accuracy-results-interpretation-discussion as comments aren't really intended for an extended discussion.